# How to create a function for an array?

Tags: arrays, typescript, function, return

I am in my first week of a programming course and been really stuck on this problem and need some help:

Given a number array of positive integers, define a function that replaces the number at index i with arr[i]

For example `fx([3, 2, 1])` would return `[3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]`.

I don't even know how to get started.

I'm using typescript.

Do I need to use a for loop? How would i define "`i`"?

Comment: If you're having this level of trouble with a programming course, the first thing you need to do is talk to your instructor.  Their job is to help you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

- To do that use [Array.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) which can create an array with a certain length of a certain item. In other words the item `3` becomes `[3, 3, 3]`
- Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform each item in your array, to array of that item. After this step your `[3, 2, 1]` will become `[ [3, 3, 3], [2, 2], [1] ]`
- Use [Arrray.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten your array. This will transform the previous 2D array into one dimension. Giving you finally the `[3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]` you're looking for

Your `fx` will then look like this:

```js
const fx = arr => arr.map(x => Array(x).fill(x)).flat();
const arr = [3, 2, 1];

console.log(fx(arr));
```